# Show Interstitial Admob ads after certain time?

Tags: admob, ads, interstitial

I wanted to add an interstitial ads to show on the mainactivity after certain time interval. I search, it seems there is no reference code to do so. Appreciate your help how do I do this? Any sample code will be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Just set a timer on your Activity that calls `interstitial.show()` when it times out.
2. ***Don't do this.*** :-) Pushing ads at your users like this is a **very** poor user experience. Much better to show them an ad at a natural break point in your app.

Comment: I would even consider both together. Show the ad at a natural break point and only after at least one hour lapsed.

Answer (score 0):

```
interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.this.interstitialAd.show();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Some explanation in addition to the code would make this answer more useful to other users.